# Swing setLayout Bug

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a simple swing program that uses the BorderLayout on eclipse IDE. I believe that i use the setLayout method properly but a given bug shows up and i have no idea how i can fix it. can someone help me how i can fix this bug? the given error is

> The method setLayout(LayoutManager) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (BorderLayout)

i have done some research but had no luck solving it. here is the code i use.

```
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BorderLayout extends JFrame {

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");

    public void initialize() {
        setTitle("BorderLayout Demo");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public BorderLayout() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        initialize();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BorderLayout();
    }

}
```

[image: here is a view of the bug on my desktop since i can't show image here]

Comment: Not that it matters much in the context of your question, but for the future, when discussing about code it's good to use correct terminology. It's not a bug, it's a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're shadowing `java.awt.BorderLayout` with your own class.

Either qualify `BorderLayout` in your call

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
```

Or, better, change your class name to something that is not ambiguous.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i didn't realize that my own class somehow overwrites the BorderLayout class and caused the compiler error. I've change my class name and now it works properly. thanks again everyone :)

Comment: No, wait, it doesn't *overwrite* the `BorderLayout` class. It's just that you have two classes with the same name and, since you didn't import `java.awt,BorderLayout` the compiler uses the only other `BorderLayout` class available, that is yours.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing an instance of your own `BorderLayout` class instead of `java.awt.BorderLayout`. Naming the class that is probably a bad idea.